# munin-node-win32: cannot use a batch file as plugin

Tags: munin

I am having trouble getting a defined a plugin which is a batch file to run with Munin-node-win32 (1.6.1).

According to the [readme](http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/munin-node-win32/README.rst), it is capable of integrating external plugins defined in the `[ExternalPlugin]` section:

```
* External Plugin:

    * A plugin that supports external plugins in the style of munin-node.

    * Configuration in [ExternalPlugin] section. Just add an entry with the 
      path to the program to run, It doesn't matter what the name of the 
      name=value pair is.

    * The output of the external program should be similar to the following,

    * Note: add quotes (") around the value if it has spaces! ::

        >disk_free.py name
        drive_free

        >disk_free.py
        drive_free_c.value 40.3635149113
        .

        >disk_free.py config
        graph_title Filesystem free (in %)
        graph_category disk
        graph_info This graph shows the amount of free space on each disk.
        graph_args --upper-limit 100 -l 0
        graph_vlabel %
        drive_free_c.label C:
        .
```

I have defined the plugin as follows:

```
[ExternalPlugin]
; For External Plugins just add an entry with the path to the program to run
; It doesn't matter what the name of the name=value pair is
rdsessions="C:\Program Files\Monitoring-Scripts\munin-rdsessions.bat"
```

And the batch file seemingly is returning the output as required by the docs:

```
C:\Program Files\Monitoring-Scripts>.\munin-rdsessions.bat name
rdsessions

C:\Program Files\Monitoring-Scripts>.\munin-rdsessions.bat
total.value "6.000000"
active.value "1.000000"
.

C:\Program Files\Monitoring-Scripts>.\munin-rdsessions.bat config
graph_title Remote Desktop Sessions
graph_category system
graph_args --upper-limit 15 -l 0 -r
graph_vlabel Sessions
graph_order total active
total.label Total sessions
active.label Active sessions
.

C:\Program Files\Monitoring-Scripts>
```

But the Munin node is not listing "rdsessions" as an available plugin upon query:

```
$ telnet rdsh-02.example.com 4949
Trying 192.168.21.85...
Connected to rdsh-02.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
# munin node at rdsh-02
list
df memory processes network cpu hdd
```

So far, I have found a [bug report for Munin-node-win32](https://code.google.com/p/munin-node-win32/issues/detail?id=17) concerning `.cmd`s as external plugins with answers hinting that the finishing dots were crucial to the plugin's functionality and revealing that a number of people had issues with integrating external plugins.

Based on this, I have set up the batch file to write the output to a temporary file prior to writing it to stdout, so I could check for non-printable characters, whitespaces and newlines. But everything looked as it probably should. I also tried removing trailing newlines for the last line in the output using the [set /p hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336754/832418), to no avail - the plugin never ever appeared in the list. I have restarted the Munin service every time I made changes to the batch file.

So what is wrong with Munin-node-win32 that it does not like my batch?

Batch listing:

```
@echo off
set OUTFILE=%TEMP%\munin-rdsessions.output

if "%1" == "config" goto config
if "%1" == "name" (echo rdsessions && goto end)

for /F "usebackq delims=, tokens=2,3,4" %%a IN (`typeperf -sc 1 "Terminaldienste\Sitzungen insgesamt" "Terminaldienste\Aktive Sitzungen" ^| find /V "(PDH-CSV"`) do (
echo total.value %%a>%OUTFILE%
echo active.value %%b>>%OUTFILE%
echo .>>%OUTFILE%
)
type %OUTFILE%
goto end

:config
type "%~dpn0.conf"
goto end

:end
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, munin-node-win32 is extremely prudent about white spaces at the end of the "name" output. So a line looking like this

```
if "%1" == "name" (echo rdsessions && goto end)
```

would cause munin-node-win32 to simply swallow the plugin definition. The white space at the end of the `echo` call has to be removed for it to work:

```
if "%1" == "name" (echo rdsessions&&goto end)
```